# Does $a$ belong to $X=\{a,1,b\}$? Is $a$ a subset of $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know this is pretty evident, but somehow I feel uncomfortable saying "It's evident" on my test... is there a way to prove (or disprove) this?

Comment: This highlights the dichotomy between points, and sets containing points. In particular in mathematics, $a$ and $\{a\}$ are two different objects. Your question has been answered well below but I just wanted to highlight this important fact.

In your example, $a$ belongs to $X$, but $a$ is not a subset of $X$, because the object "$a$" is not a set. However, to take things further, $\{a\}$ is a subset of $X$, and $\big\{\{a\}\big\}$ (the set containing the set containing $a$) neither belongs to the set, nor is a subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X=\{a,1,b\}$ then $a$ is an *element* of $X$ so:

$$a\in X$$

$A$ is a subset of $B$ if all elements from $A$ belong to $B$. For example if $A=\{a,1\}$, $B=\{a,1,b\}$ then $$A\subset B$$

It is possible that $A$ is both a subset and an element of $B$. For example:

$$A=\{a\}$$
$$B=\{a,\{a\}\}$$
$$A\subset B\quad \land \quad A\in B$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that an answer to your question could be this:

In a situation of small set (so all the operation that we make on the set are ok) we have that a set $U$ is a subset of $X$ if and only if it is an element of the power set of $X$ which is $P(X):=\{$"the set of all subsets of $X$"$\}$

There are differences between sets and elements, although in most situation they are pretty related concepts.

*For example* we always have a partial order relation on sets, that is the inclusion relation. On the elements of a set we don't have this relation, and most of the time there aren't obvious relations on elements of a set (consider complex numbers). This gives a prospective on *how* elements characterize sets, but viewing at sets gives an *eye in the sky* view of the problem, thing not always possible with elements.

I think, *but this is only a moral/naive observation*, that reasoning on elements of a set as subsets (of only one element) make all the theory of sets implode, in the sense that all the proposition and examples are quite trivial and doesn't give other informations to the object we are considering.